# Dynamics 365 Get Guid Button

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Does anyone know of a managed solution to import into Dynamics 365 that adds functionality for a custom button to copy the Guid of any entity to your clipboard?

In a previous environment we used [this one](https://nishantrana.me/2011/10/13/custom-ribbon-button-to-get-the-guid-of-the-record-in-crm-2011/)

Of course this can't be imported into the newer Dynamics 365.
I know how to parse out the Guid from the URL, but the button to autocopy it to the clipboard was amazing.

Comment: Do you want a solution to import or Chrome extensions will work for you? This should be simple to create a ribbon/command bar button & invoke the EntityId from Xrm object, may need custom js library to add it to clipboard..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Chrome Extension Level Up](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/level-up-for-dynamics-crm/bjnkkhimoaclnddigpphpgkfgeggokam?hl=en) has button for Record Id, or you can use the [bookmarklet](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/leichtbewoelkt/archive/2015/04/13/dynamics-crm-bookmarklets-v2) code. Just add the below code to a bookmark in your browser:

```
//get record id
javascript: (function () { var form = $("iframe").filter(function () { return $(this).css("visibility") == "visible" })[0].contentWindow; window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", form.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().slice(1, -1)) })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Level Up for Dynamics 365](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/level-up-for-dynamics-crm/bjnkkhimoaclnddigpphpgkfgeggokam) Chrome Extension, it provides a great variaty of common JScript actions and shortcuts to help with extensibility, diagnostics and administration

if what you need is to pulish an option to your user to get the GUID of a record and prevent the execution of other JS logic such as display all hidden attributes, then you will have to create a ribbon button and execute JS logic contained in a webresource, to make it compatible with CRM v9 and forward, past the [execution context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/executioncontext/getformcontext) to your function (PrimaryControl) and call the native Xrm function executionContext.getFormContext().data.entity.getId()

Answer (score 0):

Another extremely useful Chrome called [Dynamics Power Pane](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dynamics-crm-power-pane/eadknamngiibbmjdfokmppfooolhdidc?hl=en). Use it together with Level Up for Dynamics 365 will be very powerful.